# How do you make an interactive input loop in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a loop which asks for a command, executes the command, and then loops again. It only exits if the command entered is "exit". I have tried a couple different things, but when I run them they work once before (read-line) reads an # and then does this infinitely without waiting for input. My initial attempt looked like this:

```
(define (inputLoop)
    (define command "init")
    (do()((equal? command "exit") (display "exited successfully..."))
        (display "What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)")
        (set! command (read-line))
        (cond [(equal? command "start") (start)]
              [(equal? command "stop") (stop)]
              [else (void)])))
```

My next attempt was similar, but instead of using a do-loop, it just recursively called the function called inputLoop if the command was not "exit".

Here is a sample of the output:

```
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)start
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)
...<thousands-of-lines-here>
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)
What would you like to do?(start,stop,exit)exit
exited successfully...
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your second attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple version of what you describe:

```scm
(define (input-loop)
  (display "What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)")
  (define command (read-line))
  (cond [(string=? command "start") (start) (input-loop)]
        [(string=? command "stop")  (stop)  (input-loop)]
        [(string=? command "exit")  (displayln "exited successfully...")]        
        [else (displayln "unknown command") (input-loop)]))
```

You could also have an escape-continuation and *break* out of the loop; this comes closest to a classical `while True: [...] break` approach:

```scm
(define (input-loop)
  (let/ec break
    (let loop ()
      (display "What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)")
      (define command (read-line))
      (cond [(string=? command "start") (start)]
            [(string=? command "stop")  (stop) ]
            [(string=? command "exit")  (break)]
            [else  (displayln "unknown command")])
      (loop)))
  (displayln "exited successfully..."))
```

Note that in the second case, you can conveniently put the closing logic (`display "exited successfully"`) at the end of the procedure, whereas in the first case you need to put it into the loop, otherwise the code may be executed several times.

Example execution on command-line (OS X):

```scm
pu@pumbair: ~/Projects/L-Racket  racket input-loop.rkt
What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)a
unknown command
What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)starr
unknown command
What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)start
start!
What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)stop
stop!
What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)exit
exited successfully...
```

using this (mock-up) version:

```scm
#lang racket

(define (start) (displayln "start!"))
(define (stop)  (displayln "stop!"))

(define (input-loop)
  (let/ec break
    (let loop ()
      (display "What would you like to do? (start,stop,exit)")
      (define command (read-line))
      (cond [(string=? command "start") (start)]
            [(string=? command "stop")  (stop) ]
            [(string=? command "exit")  (break)]
            [else  (displayln "unknown command")])
      (loop)))
  (displayln "exited successfully..."))

(input-loop)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Re the second example, +theZardov, just don't get the wrong idea -- don't use `let/ec` as your all-purpose "loop escape technique" in Racket. `let/ec` is slower, which is fine for a command loop like this, but not something you want to use indiscriminately everywhere. It's best saved for situations where it would be very awkward/messy to "escape" otherwise. Those situations exist but are relatively rare in most programs, at least in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. In response to your question above, @uselpa , my second attempt was similar to your first solution. I tried yours, but I'm still getting an infinite loop after issuing a command. Using `string=?` instead of `equal?` has given me more info though. After reading and issuing the first command, read-line tries reading the command before waiting for input so it gets `eof` immediately and repeats. This causes the looping error: `string=?": contract violation expected: string? given" #<eof>`. I get the same behavior using your second solution and on DrRacket as well.

Comment: It works fine for me, both in DrRacket and on the command line (see my edit). How do you execute it, what operating system, how did you install Racket? Are you sure the problem is not in your `start` or `stop` procedure (try my mock-up version)?.

Comment: @theZardoz Any news on this?

Comment: I've been looking at it for a while and I think I know what the issue is now. You led me in the right direction in your previous comment, @uselpa, in that the issue is in my start procedure. It created places using the (place) method. What I didn't realize is that this seems to be copying the entire racket code for each place. Since I called the loop function in the top-level of the original code, each place began executing the loop concurrently upon creation. This was fixed by using (dynamic-place) instead, since it only executes the externally provided code. I'll answer to provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

After following @uselpa 's advice about checking my `start` and `stop` methods, I've come to the conclusion that my problem was in my `start` method. It created several places to run concurrently using the `(place id body ...+)` form documented in the [racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/places.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/place..rkt%29._place%29%29). The documentation states,

> The bodys close only over id plus the top-level bindings of the enclosing module

Since my code had the call to the loop in the top-level, each created place executed the loop upon creation. My solution was instead to use the `(dynamic-place module-path start-name)` form documented [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/places.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/place..rkt%29._dynamic-place%29%29). I just had to move my code to an external file. There is no access to top-level bindings from the calling code for the place code using this method.

After making these changes, I was able to successfully run both of the loop techniques provided by @uselpa in their answer, without any infinite loops or errors.